# Difference between annotating with @Tag(Tag.DIV) and extending from Div class

Tags: vaadin, vaadin10, vaadin-flow

I'm learning Vaadin 11 and I have a question. What is the difference between this:

```
public class MyClass extends Div { /... }
```

...and this?:

```
@Tag(Tag.DIV)
public class MyClass { /** }
```

According to the documentation:

> **Div class:**
> Component representing a `<div>` element.

- 

> **Tag annotation:**
> Defines the tag to use for the root element for a component created using the default Component constructor.

Looks like they do the same thing: making a class to represent a  root element. Is that so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is the server-side API. The `Div` class is really trivial by itself, but it does implement some helpful mixin interfaces through its parents, like `HasSize` and `HasStyle`. This means that you can e.g. call `myClass.setHeight("500px")` if you're extending `Div`.

On the other hand, if you use the `@Tag` annotation to tell that your `MyComponent` class has the `div` tag on the client, you don't expose any server-side methods in addition to what you decide to provide yourself. Whether this is a good thing or a bad thing depends on what kinds of features you want to provide to your class's users.

Answer (score 2):

Both ways give you a `<div>` element in the browser (except that you need to add `extends Component` to the `@Tag(Tag.DIV)` example).

The difference is that the `Div` class also defines some additional API specifically for `<div>` elements, whereas you have full control over the public API of the component if create a generic `Component` subclass with `@Tag(Tag.DIV)`.